# Xamarin Forms ListView ItemsSource

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use the ListView in Xamarin Forms, I have a List and I have to divide it depending on the day

```
var activitiesServices = new ActivitiesServices();
        var activities = activitiesServices.GetActivities();

        var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        dataTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Subject");

        var list = new ObservableCollection<Activity>();
        var list2 = new ObservableCollection<Activity>();
        var list3 = new ObservableCollection<Activity>();
        var list4 = new ObservableCollection<Activity>();
        var list5 = new ObservableCollection<Activity>();
        foreach (Activity item in activities) {
            var day = item.StartTime.DayOfWeek;
            switch ((int)day) {
                case 1:
                    list.Add(item);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    list2.Add(item);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    list3.Add(item);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    list4.Add(item);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    list5.Add(item);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }}
```

it goes well till here but when i try to fill the main list view(define in xaml) it give me an error:

```
           if (list.Count != 0) {
            monday.ItemsSource = list;
            monday.ItemTemplate = dataTemplate;
        }
        if (list2.Count != 0) {
            tuesday.ItemsSource = list2;
            tuesday.ItemTemplate = dataTemplate;
        }
        if (list3.Count != 0) {
            wednesday.ItemsSource = list3;
            wednesday.ItemTemplate = dataTemplate;
        }
        if (list5.Count != 0) {
            friday.ItemsSource = list5;
            friday.ItemTemplate = dataTemplate;
        }
        if (list4.Count != 0) {
            thursday.ItemsSource = list4;
            thursday.ItemTemplate = dataTemplate;
        }
```

this is the error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Please show the definition of the `ListView` in XAML

Comment: It's that simple <ListView x:Name="monday" BackgroundColor="White" HasUnevenRows="True"  />

Comment: You should Group your ListView instead.

Good Explanation by James Montemagno:
http://motzcod.es/post/94643411707/enhancing-xamarin-forms-listview-with-grouping

Comment: OKay thanks I'll try it

Comment: Can you add details on what is NULL?

Comment: The null reference exception is on the monday list view when I try to fil it: monday.ItemsSource = list;

Answer (score 0):

You can try the listview provided by [Syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/grouping)

Use in XAML. This defines the group header template

```
<syncfusion:SfListView x:Name="listView">
  <syncfusion:SfListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#E4E4E4">
            <Label Text="{Binding Key}"
                   FontSize="22"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                   Margin="20,0,0,0" />
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </syncfusion:SfListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
</syncfusion:SfListView>
```

[image]

It supports grouping and seems suitable for your case.